# ViewData field is always null when creating Razor page with model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

**Technical details**:

- VS Enterprise 2022 17.3.2
- dotNET 7
- Project type: ASP dotNET Core Web App MVC
- *Empty test project, all settings set to default*

**I have**:

- "AdminController" in controllers folder that consists of default "public IActionResult Index()" method (created when choosing "empty" controller template)
- Subfolder "Admin" inside "Views" and Razor page "Index" (empty template) in said folder. Page consists of next code:

```
@page
@model WebApplication1.Views.Admin.IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Manage users";
}
```

- Model for this page has next content:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace WebApplication1.Views.Admin
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

**Issue**: when starting a project and opening localhost/Admin I get an error:
`AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument.Views_Admin_Index.ViewData.get returned null.`

**There is a workaround** to all this, I have to set `ViewData["Title"] = "titlehere";` inside of  `public IActionResult Index()` in 'AdminController.cs', but this isn't how things supposed to work, a proper solution is needed. Any ideas?

I did a little debugging and I found that:

- "ViewData = null" -- in case when loading /Admin/Index
- "ViewData = (some object)" -- in case with /Index or /Home/Index (i.e. default startup page)
  For whatever reason "_Layout.cshtml" does not effect pages inside "Admin" subfolder, but View is fully operation when exact same layout gets applied to "Home" subfolder pages.

**I've tried**:

- cleaning browser cache & site data for "localhost" - didn't work
- setting "Layout = path-to-layout-file" inside Index.cshtml - didn't work, file was never opened/read by program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in official Microsoft ASP.NET Core documentation:

> @page makes the file into an MVC action, which means that it handles requests directly, without going through a controller. @page must be the first Razor directive on a page. @page affects the behavior of other Razor constructs.

**Solution**: remove `@page` tag inside your .cshtml file.

**UPD**: After hours of hard work I decided it's a good idea to NOT use Razor pages along with MVC (regardless to existing of said pages scaffolded in official Microsoft DLL in Account management view).
If you try to access  '.cshtml.cs' `@Model` inside 'cshtml' ("View") it will always be null.
You can solve this issue by changing project type to ASP dotNET Core (without MVC).

**UPD2**: You can still use custom model though, just don't inherit anything from "PageModel" class.